# log producer docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, firelens

I am trying to do performance testing with aws firelens. I have a json file with 10 sample log messages. I want to be able to produce docker logs at a set rate. ex: 10,000 log messages/sec from a docker container that will be consumed by aws firelens log collector.

Is there any open source projects that already does this? Can any of you help with creating this container?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: https://github.com/mehiX/log-generator

I made it for this purpose so if there is anything you can't do let me know and I can hopefully fix it.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: I tried to run this locally and all I am seeing is this after I run docker run  `docker run -ti --rm test -run 1000ms -g 13 -stats`
Counter: 10228
Duration: 1.000627809s and do not see any container running

Comment: please read the README as well. The stats should be false in order to see log messages. Also the container runs for the amount specified by `-run` and then dies. `-run 24h` will keep the container running for 24 hours. Also I see you don't have the latest version (I made some small improvements so it's better to pull and build again)